# How to display Automatic Alert Dialog after i swipe into particulate class in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I want to display dialog/popup window for message to user that shows **Please enter your Name** with One **ENTER** button . On click of button **ENTER**, it should  enter into database display the information. If entered is wrong user name then it should popup an error message.
Can someone help me please main i want to display dialog/popup window automatically when i swipe into particulate class.

Here main problem is  i have already extended my class to `Fragment` now for Dialog i should extended another class `DialogFragment` But in a class i can extended only one class .
Please help me out

MainActivity

{

```
package com.example.jawa.pops;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Switch;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    DATA_BASE data_base;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));

        data_base = new DATA_BASE(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = data_base.getWritableDatabase();

    }
}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (position == 0){
            fragment = new Credit();
        }
        if (position == 1){
            fragment = new Cash();
        }
        if (position == 2){
            fragment = new Reports();
        }
        if (position == 3){
            fragment = new Daily_Purchase();
        }
        if (position == 4){
            fragment = new Settings();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        String title = new String();

        if (position == 0) {
            title = "Credit";
        }
        if (position == 1) {
            title= "Cash";
        }
        if (position == 2) {
            title= "Reports";
        }
        if (position == 3) {
            title= "Daily Purchase";
        }
        if (position == 4) {
            title= "Settings";
        }
        return title;
    }
}
```

Credit.java code

```
package com.example.jawa.pops;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by jawa on 10/4/2015.
 */
public class Credit extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.credit, container, false);

    }
}
```

now when i open credit.java i want to display a dialog box automatically.

Comment: Please post code that you tried so far.

Comment: just open an `AlertDialog` in `onResume` of the `MainActivity`, since `Credit` is the first `View` of your slider

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.jawa.pops;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;  
import android.view.View;    
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Credit extends Fragment implements CreditDialog.Callback{

MainActivity mActivity;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try
    {
        mActivity = (MainActivity)activity;
    }
    catch(ClassCastException e)
    {
        Log.e("Credit", "ClassCastException e", e);
    }
}
@Override
public void onStart()
{
super.onStart();
if(mActivity !=null){
CreditDialog dialog = new CreditDialog();
dialog.setTargetFragment(this, 1); 
mActivity.showDialog(dialog);
}
}
@Override
public void onEnterPressed(String name)
{
    //manage answer
}
}
```

And here is the CreditDialog Class :

```
public class CreditDialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener
 {
 private EditText mEditText;
 private Button enterButton;

public static interface Callback
{
    public void onEnterPressed(String name);
}

public CreditDialog()
{
    // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogfragment, container);
    mEditText =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    enterButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.enterButton);
    enterButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    getDialog().setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    Callback callback = null;
    try
    {
        callback = (Callback) getTargetFragment();
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e)
    {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Callback of this class must be implemented by target fragment!", e);
        throw e;
    }

    if (callback != null)
    {
       String name="";
            if(mEditText !=null) {
             name=mEditText.getText().toString();
            }
            callback.onEnterPressed(name);
            this.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```